# How to move (image) files to other directories based on files' dates

Tags: files, date, move

I have a directory (currdir) with 24000 images on a CentOS/cPanel server.

I want to split this directory by moving images from this directory into other directories (or sub-directories inside currdir) based on image dates.

How to make it happen?

Comment: By "image date" you mean information from EXIF or file modification timestamp?

Comment: @rush file modification timestamp

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001320/shell-script-to-move-photos-into-folders-with-date-yyyymmdd/76315835#76315835) a solution for visitors looking to sort images and videos based on the creation date read from EXIF metadata.

Answer (score 2):

This will run a `find` command that outputs a shell command moving the file in a directory based on the last change time of the file. It will create the target on the directory on the fly (`mkdir -p` will not fail if directory already exists). The generated commands are then directly piped into a shell interpreter.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "mkdir -p %CY/%Cm/%Cd && mv -- '%f' %CY/%Cm/%Cd\n" | sh
```

(assumes GNU `find` for its `-printf` predicate).

Replace `%C` with `%T` for the last modification time (a generally more accurate representation  of the age of the *contents* of the file as the change time is also updated when metadata of the file is modified).

Note that this may not be the most efficient way to do it, as it will create a lot of processes to create directories ad move files. As it is for a one-shot execution, I wouldn't focus too much on this...

It assumes file names don't contain `'` characters (it constitutes a command injection vulnerability if you can't guarantee it).

You can pass the `-x` option (or `-o xtrace`) to `sh` for it to show you what it's doing, or `-e` (or `-o errexit`) for it to exit upon the first error (though with `-e`, you'd want to replace the `&&` with `;` as otherwise failures of `mkdir` would be ignored).

Comment: Re: your edit, `mkdir -p dir` will succeed if the directory already exist, and only fails if the file doesn't exist *as a directory* when it exits, in which case you do *not* want to run `cp`, hence the `&&` I had edited in. The `--` doesn't harm but is not necessary as the file paths will all start with `./`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Didn't ever noticed that `mkdir -p` didn't fail on existing directories. Thanks for pointing this out. I corrected the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

With `exiftool`:

```
exiftool -ext jpg '-Directory<FileModifyDate' -d %Y/%m/%d .
```

Would move the files with `jpg` extension in the current working directory to YYYY/MM/DD subdirectories (creating them as needed) based on the `FileModifyDate`.

`exiftool -args file.jpg` will show  you what other timestamps relevant to the  files you may use instead of `FileModifyDate`, (including those from the EXIF metadata stored by the camera in the JPEG file) such as `FileInodeChangeDate`,  `FileAccessDate`, `ModifyDate`, `DateTimeOriginal`, `CreateDate`.